# Add Text Box or Table to R highchart

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I have a highchart created in R and from the data I've calculated some statistics for the plots that I'd like to display in a text box or table. There may be different ways of accomplishing this via tooltip, or displaying a table, or a text box and I'm open to suggestions. Below is an example of what I'm attempting to create.

I've tried adding data labels with the calculated aggregate statistics but the formatting is difficult to work with.

Table example - inserted manually https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nWMt2l6jVjTqRgMbMqdV2KNIFM1Xvw2P)
 - I had to post this link because my reputation won't yet let me embed the image. My apologies.

Thanks in advance for your assistance,
Brian

Comment: Could you provide all of your code so I can run your chart?
More important question - on what condition you want to display your label and what its content should be?

Comment: How do you want to publish the graph, in a dashboard or document?